# How to determine whether a value can be assigned to a DataTable column without using exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, datatable

## The Problem

Hi there! I'm wondering whether it is possible to write this kind of C# code:

```
try
{
    // I know the dataColumn.DataType but the only way I found
    // to tell whether the value is actually assignable
    // to this column is to assign it and catch the exception
    dataRow[dataColumn] = someStringValue;
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    // Now I know, that the value is not applicable to the type
}
```

without using exceptions. My use case is that I handle a large number of rows (1000+) and I know that this will happen quite often so I want to avoid the overhead of the exception handling to gain performance. So is it possible to check this like you would do with a Dictionary?

```
bool isAssignable = SomeMagicDataHelper.TrySetValue(dataColumn, someStringValue);
if (!isAssignable)
{
    // Now I know, that the value is not applicable to the type
}
```

I'm aware that this could be done with help of reflection but I guess that such a solution would be even slower than the exception approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd implement it something like this. The core of it is based on the idea that there's a finite list of types that the column can be. Most of [those types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) provide a `TryParse`, and the others (`string` and `byte[]`) are simpler. But since you can't call the *static* `TryParse` method via an interface, and calling it via reflection is a bit ugly and slow, I decided to write it as a template that generates the different statements. This keeps it fast, and lets you write one maintainable template instead of a monstrous code file.

Save this in a `.tt` ([T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)) file:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace MyApp
{
    public static class SomeMagicDataHelper
    {
        public static bool TrySetValue(DataRow dataRow, DataColumn dataColumn, object value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    if (!dataColumn.AllowDBNull)
                        return false;
                    else
                    {
                        dataRow[dataColumn] = DBNull.Value;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // if the types match exactly, a direct assignment will work
                if (value.GetType() == dataColumn.DataType)
                {
                    dataRow[dataColumn] = value;
                    return true;
                }
                // otherwise, we'll do a TryParse
                switch (dataColumn.DataType.FullName)
                {
                    case "<#= typeof(string).FullName #>":
                        dataRow[dataColumn] = value;
                        return true;
                    case "<#= typeof(byte[]).FullName #>":
                        return false;
<# foreach (var type in new[] { typeof(Boolean), typeof(Byte), typeof(Char), typeof(DateTime), typeof(Decimal), typeof(Double), typeof(Guid), typeof(Int16), typeof(Int32), typeof(Int64), typeof(SByte), typeof(Single), typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(UInt16), typeof(UInt32), typeof(UInt64) }) {
#>                    case "<#= type.FullName #>":
                    {
                        <#= type.Name #> tryValue;
                        if (<#= type.Name #>.TryParse(value.ToString(), out tryValue))
                        {
                            dataRow[dataColumn] = tryValue;
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
<# } #>
                }

                // last resort, might throw an exception
                dataRow[dataColumn] = value;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log ex, this shouldn't be a common thing
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought of something like this ... just hoped there would be some kind of built-in way to do it :-)

Comment: I finally went with this approach and it's blazingly fast compared to always catching the `ArgumentException` (same process 60sec -> 3sec). Thank you VERY much for this :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would write an extension method that checks if the type is a valid datacolumn type:

```
public static bool IsValidType<T>(this DataColumn col, T someStringValue)
{
  return col.Datatype == typeof(T);
}
```

then do:

```
if (column.IsValidType(someStringValue)
{
  dataRow[dataColumn] = someStringValue    
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it only works on columns and values with exactly matching types. What I want is to know in advance that for an int column the value "4" is valid and "four" isn't

Comment: Explain what you mean by "Know in advance". When do you need to know?

Comment: The data I'm filling my `DataTable`s with is given as string values from a file and I'm dynamically creating and filling the tables. In case a value should be assigned to a column that is not valid I want to know it before I do the actual assignment to a cell so that no exception handling is required